# SELECT COUNT non-zero cells mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, count

How can I count do a `COUNT` for values of `cc.audio` that are non-zero from this query?

```
SELECT cc.audio FROM
(SELECT cid, SUM(mp='audio') audio, SUM(mp='text') texts, SUM(mp='video') video
FROM
  ( SELECT ccm.cid, cmp.cmid, cmp.mp
    FROM a as ccm
    INNER JOIN b as cmp
    ON ccm.mid = cmp.cmid) AS tmp
    GROUP BY cid) AS cc
```

Sample:

```
cid audio texts video   
----------------------
1    1      1     1
2    1      1     1 

Expected results: 2
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question suggests:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
      SELECT cid, SUM(mp='audio') as audio, SUM(mp='text') as texts, SUM(mp='video') as video
      FROM a ccm INNER JOIN
           b cmp
           ON ccm.mid = cmp.cmid
      GROUP BY cid
    ) cc
WHERE audio > 0;
```

Although I simplified your query, it is basically the same. There are other ways to write this, that don't involve any subqueries.